# How to test file import timing scenario in JMeter

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, blazemeter, database-testing

I came across one scenario to test in JMeter.
There are multiple text files with multiple line data and need to import those in web application.
I need to know

1. How much time taken by every line and file to import in my application.
2. Performance level of database when imported data is getting stored.

How can I test that scenario in JMeter.
I a using blazemeter to test the scenario.
What set up need to set in JMeter for this.

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter's [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler will give you the time from the beginning of the request till the end of the request either for single file or multiple files if you're going to upload several in one shot. If you need an overview per "line" you can do something like:

   - read the current "line" from the file using i.e. __StringFromFile() function
   - wait until it's available in the corresponding database table using [While Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-while-controller-jmeter) and [JDBC Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JDBC_Request) sampler
   - both HTTP Request sampler and the While Controller can be put under the [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) so you could have end-to-end time
2. If the system is not asynchronous, i.e. you're getting the response after sending the file to the web application once the file processing is done the response time of the HTTP Request sampler will include the time required to insert the data to the database so you need to just check that it's not growing. Also you can check your database [slow query logs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/slow-query-log.html) to see if there is something suspicious there.

Comment: Thanks, I will check it by implementing.

Comment: Hi, It looks quite complex , can you please add proper steps or share a tutorial?